# Stop javascript functions from running

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a few validations happening in the first step of a form.

When the next button is clicked, an age verification is run, if it is true then it runs three functions.

```
function checkAge(form)
{ 
  return false;
}

else {
  validate('theForm','email');
  hideFormOne();
  showPartTwo();
  return false;
};
```

and the function is

```
function validate(form_id,email){
  var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
  var address = document.forms[form_id].elements[email].value;
  if(reg.test(address) == false) {
    alert('Invalid Email Address');      
    return false;
  }
}
function hideFormOne(container1)
{
  document.getElementById('container1').style.display='none';
}
function showPartTwo(container2)
{
  document.getElementById('container2').style.display='block';
}
```

My problem is, if the email is invalid, the alert pops up, but then when that is closed it continues to run the hide and show functions.  I need it to only run the hide/show functions if the email is valid.

Comment: The else below checkAge(form) function is part of what if condition?

Comment: @burak, i left that bit out because it is lengthy and not relevant to my question
@answers, thanks for all the great feedback, i am going to try these out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `validate` function returns true or false, you can use that value to decide what to do after the function has executed.

```
if(validate('theForm', 'email')) {
   hideFormOne();
   showPartTwo();
}
```

The above is a terse way of writing

```
var isValid = validate('theForm', 'email');
if(isValid) {
   hideFormOne();
   showPartTwo();
}
```

... where `isValid` gets the value that is returned from `validate`

Comment: I tried this and it does stop the functions from running if it false.  However, now nothing happens if it is true..

Comment: I got it to work by creating an else statement in the email validation and moving the hide/show functions up there.

Comment: To get it to work how it is currently you'd need to add `return true` to the end of your validate function.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `validate()` returns false, then return false from the calling function:

```
if (!validate('theForm','email'))
{
    return false;
}

hideFormOne();
showPartTwo();
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Then change your logic in this part of the code to take into account the return value of `validate`

```
if (validate('theForm','email')) {
    hideFormOne();
    showPartTwo();
}
return false;
```

};

You will also need to change `validate` to return `true` if the e-mail address is valid.

Answer (score 0):

change your `validate` function to return true, if valid.

then:

```
else {
  if validate('theForm','email') {
    hideFormOne();
    showPartTwo();
  };
  return false;
};
```